# Concurrency in RabbitMQ

Tags: c#, multithreading, concurrency, rabbitmq

After a week of coding and searching forums, it seems timely to ask...

I have a C# application which processes messages sent by RabbitMQ using EventingBasicConsumer. I want to process several messages concurrently, so I have instantiated a few channels (8 in this case) on the same connection, each with a single consumer. I have then attached an event-handler to each consumer's Received event. Based on all my readings so far, this setup should allow the event-handler to be triggered concurrently by the consumers, each running in its own thread. But in my case consumers receive messages sequentially only after the a previous consumer acknowledges its message.

Has anyone else experienced this behavior? Is my understanding correct that the processing should technically be concurrent in this case?

Below is a basic code to better illustrate the issue:

```
Initialise() {
    ConsumerChannels_ = new IModel[ConsumerCount_];
    Consumers_ = new EventingBasicConsumer[ConsumerCount_];
    for (int i = 0; i < ConsumerCount_; ++i)
    {
         ConsumerChannels_[i] = Connection_.CreateModel();
         Consumers_[i] = new EventingBasicConsumer(ConsumerChannels_[i]);
         Consumers_[i].Received += MessageReceived;
    }
}

MessageReceived(IBasicConsumer sender, BasicDeliverEventArgs e)
{
    int id = GetConsumerIndex(sender);
    Log_.Debug("Consumer " + id + ": processing started...");         
    // do some time consuming processing here
    sender.Model.BasicAck(e.DeliveryTag, false);
    Log_.Debug("Consumer " + id + ": processing ended.");
}
```

What I expect to see is something like: // concurrent processing

> Consumer 1: processing started...
>
> Consumer 2: processing started...
>
> Consumer 3: processing started...
>
> ...
>
> Consumer 6: processing ended.
>
> Consumer 7: processing ended.
>
> Consumer 8: processing ended.

But what I get instead is: // sequential processing

> Consumer 1: processing started...
>
> Consumer 1: processing ended.
>
> Consumer 2: processing started...
>
> Consumer 2: processing ended.
>
> ...
>
> Consumer 8: processing started...
>
> Consumer 8: processing ended.

Any ideas on how to proceed would be most appreciated.

Comment: Although you have multiple consumers they are all running on the same thread.  You need to spin up threads and create a consumer for each.  You could also always have one consumer and run your processing application multiple times.  Or, shameless self promotion here, use something like [Shuttle.Esb](http://shuttle.github.io/shuttle-esb/) to do the heavy lifting :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to ways to do that:

Increase the concurrency by adding your own Thread-pool inside:

```
MessageReceived(IBasicConsumer sender, BasicDeliverEventArgs e) {
    int id = GetConsumerIndex(sender);
    Log_.Debug("Consumer " + id + ": processing started...");         
    // do some time consuming processing here
    // PUT your thread-pool here and process the messages inside the thread

    sender.Model.BasicAck(e.DeliveryTag, false);
    Log_.Debug("Consumer " + id + ": processing ended."); }

}
```

Note: the `BasicAck` can be called in different threads.

or

you can add more consumers to the queue, by using the `QoS=1` you can consume the messages in round-robin

Comment: +1 @Gabriele.  @Kia  We essentially do this.  It simplifies too: Only one consumer as far as RabbitMQ is concerned.  Also, no need to spin up threads / manage a `ThreadPool` manually.  Placing the message processing as tasks onto a `TaskScheduler` can handle all that. Easy to scale the parallelism up/down within the same consumer by varying the max parallelism of the `TaskScheduler` (several flavours of scheduler offer this). Dedicated thread pools versus sharing the default `ThreadPool` a wider discussion, depending how many such consumers you have and degree of isolation needed.

Comment: Adding my own thread pool did the trick. It was helpful to know I could call BasicAck from multiple threads of my own. For anyone interested I also introduced a simple blocking throttle mechanism (using Monitor.Wait and Monitor.Pulse) to custom control the concurrency level, with channel.BasicQos(0, 10000, false).

Answer (score 3):

You can actually set the number of parallel processing tasks when creating your `ConnectionFactory`!

```cs
ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory
{
    ConsumerDispatchConcurrency = 2,
};
```

The default value is 1, which is serial/sequential processing.

I found this out by dissecting the [.NET client's source code](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-dotnet-client/blob/master/projects/RabbitMQ.Client/client/impl/ConsumerDispatching/ConsumerDispatcherChannelBase.cs). Here's the interesting part (`concurrency` is set from `ConsumerDispatchConcurrency`):

```cs
Func<Task> loopStart = ProcessChannelAsync;
if (concurrency == 1)
{
    _worker = Task.Run(loopStart);
}
else
{
    var tasks = new Task[concurrency];
    for (int i = 0; i < concurrency; i++)
    {
        tasks[i] = Task.Run(loopStart);
    }
    _worker = Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}
```

But beware, this can result in race conditions! The property has this remark:

> For concurrency greater than one this removes the guarantee that consumers handle messages in the order they receive them. In addition to that consumers need to be thread/concurrency safe.

Comment: Additionally, I've found that the .Net Rabbit client ignores / limits the `ConsumerDispatchConcurrency` if the [QoS prefetch size](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8179850/314291) isn't also >> 1

Comment: this makes sense, since if the prefetch count is 1, you can only have at most 1 un-ack'd message