# Is it safe to call RabbitMQ BasicAck/BasicReject on a different thread?

Tags: c#, concurrency, rabbitmq, consumer

I've done quite a bit of searching but I can't find a definitive answer to this question. I also can't find anything in the documentation that makes it absolutely clear (to me).

Is it safe to call `BasicAck`/`BasicReject` on multiple different threads, potentially at the same time?

An example:

```
var consumer = new EventingBasicConsumer(channel);
consumer.Received += (sender, ea) =>
{
  _ = Task.Run(async () =>
  {
    // simulate processing time
    await Task.Delay(rand.Next(2000, 10001));

    // send acknowledgement
    channel.BasicAck(ea.DeliveryTag, false);
  });
}
```

If the answer is no, what is the correct way to concurrently process multiple messages from the queue, and acknowledge as processing completes?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. One way to do that is to dispatch messages to workers. Let's say you have 20 workers then you can use round robin to decide that which worker should process the current message. So, you 20 messages can be processed in parallel and each message is processed only by one of the workers.

Comment: Thanks @PeterCsala.  Undertstood, but after a worker has finished processing a message, is it safe for the worker to call channel.BasicAck, keeping in mind other workers may be making the call at the same time?

Comment: As a side note, the `_ = Task.Run(...` creates a fire-and-forget task, whose potential failure will pass unnoticed. Making your event handler `async` (`consumer.Received += async (sender, ea) =>...`) should be more responsible in that regard. [`async void`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming#avoid-async-void) methods do not hide their failure under the carpet.

Comment: Thanks @TheodorZoulias, it's just an example to demonstrate how BasicAck might end up being called on multiple threads.

Comment: [Based on this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12024241/c-sharp-rabbitmq-client-thread-safety) `channel` is not thread-safe.

Comment: @PeterCsala I can find examples of people saying one way or the other, which is why I'm not sure which is true.  Example here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40338774/concurrency-in-rabbitmq

Comment: Based on the implementation of [BasicAck](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-dotnet-client/blob/main/projects/RabbitMQ.Client/client/framing/Model.cs#L240) it calls the [ModelSend](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-dotnet-client/blob/main/projects/RabbitMQ.Client/client/impl/ModelBase.cs#L388) which uses a `_flowControlBlock` variable. And that is a `ManualResetEventSlim`, so according to my understanding it prevents multiple `Session.Transmit`.

Comment: It calls the version of ```ModelSend``` that takes a single parameter though, which omits the ```_flowControlBlock``` variable... I think.